# Qtranslate duplicates content in visual editor of Theme VamTam

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, qtranslate

I have a problem. When using the plugin qTranslate, and I'm saving content of my webpage, plugin is doubling everything on this page. I'm using VamTam's Theme Church and events. Can somebody help me?